# how to implement the Client side in JAX-RS tutorial

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, jersey

okay let me be clear with this :
i am following [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) tutorial.

And at the end of every part author implements the Client part.
Well i have done everything correctly of every section(5,6,7) upto the client parts.

I just dont know how to implement the client-side.

[NOTE: This might be trivial for you but i am a noob at this whole thing (java,jersey,tomcat) ,so please be kind and thoughtful in your instructions !! ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay found some meaningful concepts...
[this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-tomcat/) might be the answer for others too (as it is to me) !

Here the article is very vague (what code where to put) but the concepts are to the point.
Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see, you're just supposed to copy the clients from the tutorial to test your services.

Anyway, using REST Service with a client is easy. Configuration is in this part of code:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
```

getBaseURI() returns the appropriate URL to your REST service.
After that just call

```
service.path("rest").path("hello")
       .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class))
```

**path** is the base path to your REST service

**hello** is the path assigned to your class by annotation:

```
@Path("/hello") public class Hello {
```

Comment: well let me ask again...how to test the service as a client... (is it the same way as to browse to the address : http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.jaxb/rest/todo ??)

Comment: Browsing there would be the same as: service.path("rest").path("todo")    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).get(String.class))